# Exponential decay and time constants

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The time constant τ is the amount of time that
an exponentially decaying quantity takes to decay by a factor of 1/e. Because 1/e
is approximately 0.368, τ is the amount of time that the quantity takes to decay to
approximately 36.8% of its original amount.
(a) How are the time constant τ and the decay rate λ related?

I used the decay model:

$r = r_0e^{\lambda t} $

Where t = time

r = amount of the particular exponentially decaying matter at time t

$-\lambda$ = decay rate

$e^{-\lambda t} = \frac{r}{r_0}$

Then I let $\frac{r}{r_0} = \frac{1}{e}$ and $t = τ$

$e^{-\lambda τ} = \frac{1}{e}$

Simplifying I got, $τ = \frac{1}{\lambda}$

Is this the correct way to show that the time constant is inversely proportional to the decay rate?

(b) Express the time constant in terms of the half-life.

I'm not sure how to do this, do I just set $\frac{r}{r_0}  = 0.5$?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In both cases, you are absolutely correct. You can prove this [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay)

Comment: Generally speaking, people don't usually go to Wikipedia to prove things. Perhaps the OP can prove his suggested solution is correct *using* the information from that Wikipedia article?

Comment: @StefG Thanks for the link! I'm just a little confused because their proof uses integration by parts and not $t = \tau$ to show that the mean lifetime or time constant is related to the decay rate: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay#Derivation_of_the_mean_lifetime

Comment: @AsafKaragila You are correct and I forgot that I am in the Mathematics board and used "prove" in a rather sloppy way where I should have used "check".

Comment: @user51462 As this reflects the mathematical representation of a very general law, it might be worth to all sorts of advanced math. However, in this case I think that the wiki authors should use a more pedagogic approach as the general thing I refer to is any exponential growth, decline / decay, or approach to a limit. Based on initial or final boundary conditions, the same differential equation (i.e. current growth is proportional to current value) can give you the formula e.g. for the temperature of a heated mass that approaches ambient temperature.

Answer (score 0):

Half life=$ln 2$*$\tau$ and $\tau$=1/$\lambda$

Answer (score 0):

i think it's easier to calculate it graphically by taking slope from origin point and intersect with original graph and then multiply 0.368 * final value the point in y axis and the intersect with x axis represent time constant

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the time constant is the time it takes for $r(\tau)=r_0e^{-\lambda \tau}$ to be equal to $(\frac{1}{e})r_0$. One can easily verify this by letting $\tau=\frac{1}{\lambda}$.